# How to send a file using FTP?

Tags: magento2.3, csv, ftp

I have a sample CSV file and want to send it to another server using FTP. I have successfully connected FTP but couldn't able to send the file.

In the FTP where I want to send, there are 2 folders named Import and Export. I have checked those folders but I can't see the file which I sent. I didn't get any error as well. So, I'm not sure, where am I wrong.

In order to send the file using FTP, I have followed the below link:

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-upload-file-to-ftp-server-by-coding-in-magento-2/

Would anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Code:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$sftp = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp');
$open =  $sftp->open(
                    array(
                        'host' => 'hostname',
                        'username' => 'xyz',
                        'password' => 'pwd',
                        'port' =>22,
                        'passive' => true
                    )
                );

if ($open) {
      $fileName = ‘sample.csv’;
      $content = file_get_contents(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR . '/' . $fileName);
      $this->ftp->write(self::FILE_NAME_ON_FTP, $content);
      $this->ftp->close();
 }

 if(is_null($connection)){
      echo "true";
      //Here is code ....
 }else{
      echo "false";
 }
```

Comment: Can you please update your code in question ?

Comment: I have added the code in question. Please have a look and help me.

Comment: What is the value in `self::FILE_NAME_ON_FTP` ?

Comment: First of all, I have put the filename which is in my local. That wasn't worked. So I have removed that and put the original code as I mentioned in URL which is on question.

Comment: add file name instead of `self::FILE_NAME_ON_FTP`. and check root folder of the server...Means before public_html

Comment: Try Naresh Rupareliya answer. seems you have to change the `$this->ftp` into `$sftp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please replace your code with below content

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');

$sftp = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp');
$open =  $sftp->open(
            array(
                'host' => '',
                'username' => '',
                'password' => '',
                'port' =>22,
                'passive' => true
            )
        );

$fileName = 'sample.csv';
$content = file_get_contents($directory->getPath('var') . '/' . $fileName);
$sftp->write('/Import/test1.csv', $content);
$sftp->close();
echo "File uploaded..!";
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks @Kishan Savaliya

Comment: You're welcome @Mohammad :)

Comment: What If I want to connect to SFTP via controller? Is it possible?

Comment: Hi @KishanSavaliya can you help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302603/magento-2-override-add-wishlist-controller

Answer (score 2):

Please replace your code with below code and check:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$sftp = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp');
$open =  $sftp->open(
                    array(
                        'host' => 'hostname',
                        'username' => 'xyz',
                        'password' => 'pwd',
                    )
                );

if ($open) {
      $fileName = 'sample.csv'; // create sample.csv file in var folder
      $content = file_get_contents(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR . '/' . $fileName);
      $sftp->write('yourprojectpath/test.csv', $content); //please give full path of your hosting root project path and create first test.csv file
      $sftp->close();
 } else {
    echo "Something wrong in hosting detail";
 }
```

please replace code in below core file or override in your module. because open function nothing to return. we need to return true when our hosting details are true

> /vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Io/Sftp.php

**From :**

```
public function open(array $args = [])
    {
        if (!isset($args['timeout'])) {
            $args['timeout'] = self::REMOTE_TIMEOUT;
        }
        if (strpos($args['host'], ':') !== false) {
            list($host, $port) = explode(':', $args['host'], 2);
        } else {
            $host = $args['host'];
            $port = self::SSH2_PORT;
        }
        $this->_connection = new \phpseclib\Net\SFTP($host, $port, $args['timeout']);
        if (!$this->_connection->login($args['username'], $args['password'])) {
            throw new \Exception(
                sprintf("Unable to open SFTP connection as %s@%s", $args['username'], $args['host'])
            );
        }
    }
```

**To :**

```
public function open(array $args = [])
    {
        if (!isset($args['timeout'])) {
            $args['timeout'] = self::REMOTE_TIMEOUT;
        }
        if (strpos($args['host'], ':') !== false) {
            list($host, $port) = explode(':', $args['host'], 2);
        } else {
            $host = $args['host'];
            $port = self::SSH2_PORT;
        }
        $this->_connection = new \phpseclib\Net\SFTP($host, $port, $args['timeout']);
        if (!$this->_connection->login($args['username'], $args['password'])) {
            throw new \Exception(
                sprintf("Unable to open SFTP connection as %s@%s", $args['username'], $args['host'])
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried with your code but still I can't see my file in Server.

Comment: any error getting when u ran this script??

Comment: Do I need to put the folder name while sending my file since in FTP I have 2 folders?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: can u please add your ftp folder path before 'test.csv'

Comment: I have to add into this line of code, $sftp->write('test.csv', $content); ?

Comment: yes add and check!.

Comment: I have added the folder path as like this $sftp->write('/Import/test.csv', $content); but still can't upload it. Please guide me.

Comment: Code updated. check and let me know orking for you or not. please first check your $open variable returned TRUE or null. if it will return null then problem in your hosting details