# Magento 2 override add wishlist controller?

Tags: magento2, wishlist, addtowishlist, multiplewishlist

I tried to override add wishlist controller from the custom module but it's not working.

app/code/Demo/Wishlist/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
<preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add" type="Demo\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Demo/Wishlist/Controller/Index/Add.php

```
 <?php

namespace Demo\Wishlist\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Add extends \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface
     */
    protected $wishlistProvider;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    protected $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        Validator $formKeyValidator
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->wishlistProvider = $wishlistProvider;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        parent::__construct($context, $customerSession, $wishlistProvider, $productRepository, $formKeyValidator);
    }

    /**
     * Adding new item
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @throws NotFoundException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "From custom module calling";
        exit;

    }
}
```

I have followed the below reference link in the clean default magento2.3.2 EE but no luck.

http://hkpatel201.blogspot.com/2017/02/magento-2-overriderewrite-wishlist-controller.html

Can any one know the reason what I was missed here?

Answer (score 1):

EE Version should using MultipleWishlist instead of wishlist, so you should override MultipleWishlist

```
<preference for="Magento\MultipleWishlist\Controller\Index\Add"
            type="Custom\Module\Controller\Wishlist\Add"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass dependency to parent class in construct of child controller.

Please use below code

```
 public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        Validator $formKeyValidator
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;         
        $this->wishlistProvider = $wishlistProvider;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        parent::__construct($context, $customerSession, $wishlistProvider, $productRepository, $formKeyValidator);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @prasant let me check

Comment: No @prasant it's not working

Comment: i have tired this aswell but no luck http://hkpatel201.blogspot.com/2017/02/magento-2-overriderewrite-wishlist-controller.html   can you help me

Comment: @NagarajuK, What error you're getting if you're using this solution ?

Comment: No error @KishanSavaliya still vendor module changes only calling.

Comment: Okay give me few mins.. sending you solution.

Comment: Thanks @KishanSavaliya

Comment: after adding this code you need to remove generated or need to run compile code

Comment: @PrashantValanda can you please suggest me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303117/magento-2-restrict-a-add-wishlist-product

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code in your `di.xml` file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Wishlist\Add"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Wishlist/Add.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Wishlist;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Add extends \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface
     */
    protected $wishlistProvider;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    protected $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        Validator $formKeyValidator
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->wishlistProvider = $wishlistProvider;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        parent::__construct($context, $customerSession, $wishlistProvider, $productRepository, $formKeyValidator);
    }

    /**
     * Adding new item
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @throws NotFoundException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "From custom module wishlist has been calling";
        exit;           
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I will go through this & let u know in the 10 mints

Comment: No luck @krishan its not working

Comment: scope of the di.xml whether we need to change?

Comment: Can you please check where you're adding di.xml and above php file that module is enabled or not ?

Comment: app/code/Demo/WishlistRestriction/etc/di.xml I have tried

Comment: version is Magento/2.3 (Enterprise)

Comment: Can you please update content of above both files in your question ?

Comment: I have updated my question with code please review it. i am using clean default Magento 2.3 Enterprise

Comment: There is not anything wrong with your code, don't know why that is not working. You confirmed your module is enabled ? Please check that once.

Comment: Can you guide me hwo to override using before plugin concept?

Comment: can u suggest me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303117/magento-2-restrict-a-add-wishlist-product

Comment: Hi Kishan  can u please help me on this
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304647/magento-2-hide-shipping-methods-based-on-product-attribute

Comment: @KishanSavaliya Can you pls help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330889/57334 thanks.