# Magento 2 how to restrict add wish list a product

Tags: magento2, plugin, wishlist, before-plugin, addtowishlist

I would like to stop adding products to the wishlist based on the product attribute how to do that? I would like to use the plugin concept instead of overriding the entire controller file.
`Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add`. 
But I unable to stop redirecting to a wishlist page after satisfied my condition. Please review and let me know how to do that?

app/code/Vendor/Wishlist/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <type name="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add">
           <plugin name="AddWishlistRestriction" type="Vendor\Wishlist\Plugin\AddWishlist" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
       </type>
    </config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Wishlist/Plugin/AddWishlist.php

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        dataHelper $dataHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository

    ) {  
        $this->dataHelper         = $dataHelper;
        $this->messageManager     = $messageManager;
        $this->redirect           = $redirect;
        $this->productRepository  = $productRepository;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $context->getResultRedirectFactory();
        $this->request = $context->getRequest();


    }

    /**
     * Plugin for restrict wishlist 
    */
    public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add $subject)
    {
        echo "before execute method is calling".
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by the following below code using **aroundExecute()** method since it has returns value instead of **beforeExecute()** and **afterExecute()** methods.

Now It's working as expected.

```
<?php    
namespace Vendor\Wishlist\Plugin;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Vendor\Wishlist\Helper\Data as dataHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
/**
 * Class AddWishlist
 * @package Vendor\Wishlist\Plugin
 */
class AddWishlist
{
    /**
     * @var dataHelper
    */
    protected $dataHelper;

    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
    */
    protected $messageManager;

    protected $redirect;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
    */
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        dataHelper $dataHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {  
        $this->dataHelper         = $dataHelper;
        $this->messageManager     = $messageManager;
        $this->redirect           = $redirect;
        $this->productRepository  = $productRepository;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $context->getResultRedirectFactory();
        $this->request = $context->getRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Plugin for restrict wishlist 
    */
    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {              
        $requestParams = $this->request->getParams();
        $productId = isset($requestParams['product']) ? (int)$requestParams['product'] : null;
        if (!$productId) {
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $product = null;
        }

        /*If wishlist restriction enabled */
        if($this->dataHelper->getWishlistRestrictionModuleEnabled() && $product)
        {
            $wishlistStoreConfigValues=[];
            $productAttributeValues =[];
            $data = explode(',',$product->getData('availability'));
            foreach($data as $value) {
                $attr=$product->getResource()->getAttribute('availability');
                if ($attr->usesSource()) {
                    $productAttributeValues[] = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($value);
                }
            }
            $wishlistStoreConfigValues=$this->dataHelper->getWishlistRestrictionValues();
            $restrictionFlag = (count(array_intersect($wishlistStoreConfigValues, $productAttributeValues))) ? 'restricted' : 'notrestricted';
                if($restrictionFlag === 'restricted') {
                    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                    $this->messageManager->addNotice(__('Sorry, You can\'t add this product to wishlist'));
                    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
                    return $resultRedirect; 
                }
        }
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```